# Arcpy/python Syntax Error. Variable Creation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I'm having a problem when trying to create a new variable within python.

```
i = datetime.datetime.now()
tme = i.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print tme
```

This portion of the code creates a date variable (**tme**) in the format, 10/02/2015. It functions properly.

The second portion will create a expression variable.

```
exp = "DATE = '"tme"'"
print exp
```

This portion does not function properly. The problem occurs when I enter the **tme** variable.

The result I want python to output is a variable which prints:

**DATE = '10/02/2015'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code should work other than I think you just forgot a few + signs. Try:

```
exp = "DATE = '" + tme + "'"
```

If you have two strings next to each other Python will auto concatenate them, but it will not auto concatenate a string and a variable, even if that variable is a string.  Example:

```
a = 'Hello ''World'
print a
```

should print Hello World

But the following would NOT work and would result in a syntax error like you are getting:

```
b = 'World'
a = 'Hello 'b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exp = "DATE = '" + tme + "'"
```

It was that simple!